# Django - Best way to merge two identical apps

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design, django-models

I recently came onto a project in which we have two applications that are virtually identical. We are using Django 1.4 and Postgresql 8.4. Both models have the following:

```
  class Author(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institution,blank=True, null=True)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank,blank=True, null=True)

  class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_institution = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=False, null=False)
    type = models.ForeignKey(InstitutionType, blank=False, null=False)

  class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_TYPE,blank=True,null=True)

  class InstitutionType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Is there a way to easily merge the two, either through SQL or through Django? I'm not quite sure what the best approach would be. My only issue is that there is a lot of foreign key references. Is there a good way in which you could change the primary keys of one application's table to be higher than the other application (essentially reassign primary keys in the second table starting where the first table ends) and have them trickle down and then eventually merge the two tables? Any sort of feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: How will each app know which records belong to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what Alexander is suggesting to you is not to your linking, you can use [django multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) support to:

- Keep both apps running on the same database and models
- Use a migration/sync script while you slowly decouple both models so that only one is being used
- Write tests :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most difficult thing in merging are models.
If you use Django you should use South too. If you don't - try it.
Take first application as a base. Add fields from second application and create schemamigration.
Then move your data with datamigration from second application.
Merge your code from the second app.